# how do i make .load work when i append a variable to the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append the clicked href to my url string of my .load method and load in a specific portion of the page i've called, unfortunatley when I append the variable a lot of elements seem to be duplicated on my page?

Basically I want my .load method to look like .load('http://localhost/folio1.html #inner');

But my current code loads in all of the folio1.html page:

Snippet from object wcd:

```
instance.selectors.banner.load('http://localhost/'+url+'#inner');

$('a').on('click', function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    wcd.toggleBanner(url);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Can someone advise how I append the url variable to the .load url and only retrieve the content in #inner?

Comment: "and only retrieve the content in #inner?" .load() doesn't retrieve content from the page, it inserts it INTO the page.

Comment: +1 because of the anonymous downvotes! I hate that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing a space:

```
instance.selectors.banner.load('http://localhost/'+url+'#inner');
```

vs

```
instance.selectors.banner.load('http://localhost/'+url+' #inner');
```